# C++ do while not looping

Tags: c++, c++11, while-loop, do-while

I understand I can just use for-loop to define prime number, but before I implement for loop into that topic, I had a thought that I maybe could make one with while loop or do-while.
Somehow, my do-while loop seems not to be working correctly.

My theory was that I could find prime number for checking the remainder of divisor where divisor keeps decreasing by 1 until divisor reaches 1. (Although 'until divisor reaches 1.' part is not in the code, I would assumed remainder of 0 would appear anyway before divisor goes below 0.)

However, it keeps halting before remainder reaches 0.
What did I do wrong?
I've even tried both instead of `(remainder<1 && remainder!=1)`below but still no luck.

```
while (remainder<1)
 while (remainder==1)

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number, divisor, remainder;
    cin >> number;
    divisor=number-1;
    cout << "You've put " << number << ".\n";
    do {
      divisor = divisor - 1;
      remainder=number%divisor;
    }
    while (remainder<1 && remainder!=1);
    cout << divisor << "  "  << remainder << "  " << number << "  "  << "Divisor, remainder, number\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is backwards: `number=divisor-1` should be `divisor=number-1`.

Comment: The second condition is implied by the first. If `remainder` is less than 1 it clearly isn't 1

Comment: I think the condition you want is `while(divisor > 1 && remainder != 0)`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @user4581301 So the condition regarding remainder should be changed?

Comment: @Barmar omg this works. Would you please explain why mine was not working? I had no doubt remainder would reach 0 before divisor becomes 1, so I didn't include that in condition.. and why divisor>1 not divisor>=1 or divisor=1?

Comment: I reverted the code in the question. The solution should be put into an answer, the question needs to keep the broken code so readers can see what the problem was and how it was solved.

Comment: @Minjae The `while()` condition states the criteria that should keep repeating, not the condition that should stop the loop. So you keep looping as long as the remainder is **not** zero.

Comment: You're right that checking `divisor > 1` is redundant, since the remainder will always be 0 when divisor gets to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have a typo in your variable assignment. This line:

```
number = divisor - 1;
```

should be:

```
divisor = number - 1;
```

The `while()` condition should be `while (remainder != 0)`, so that the loop keeps repeating as long as you haven't found a divisor. If you want to be more explicit, you could use `while (divisor > 1 && remainder != 0)`. There's no need to repeat when `divisor == 1` because that's a divisor of all integers.

Comment: Am I missing something? I mean, my question is perfectly answered, but I still don't get it. in my do part, divisor keep decreasing by 1 and remainder would reach 0 if the loop continued.
I thought while(divisor > 1 && remainder != 0) would stop the loop immediately as the divisor is larger than 1 and remainder can't be 0 right after do is executed once.

Comment: Eventually `divisor` will become `1`. Every integer is divisible by 1, so `remainder` will be `0` when that happens, and the loop will stop.

Comment: so, in my head, 'while(divisor >= 1 && remainder == 0)' sounds right, but this does stop the loop somehow.

Comment: is it because I used do-while? If it was just while loop, I could be correct?

Comment: You still have it backwards. It should be `&& remainder != 0`.

Comment: The only difference between `while` and `do-while` is whether the test is done before or after the body. Since you set `remainder` in the body, it has to be `do-while`.